# Removing old GRE scores when applying to PhD program for a second time

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, application, gre

I would like to apply to a PhD program for a second time, but without my old scores being imported from my first application. I had sent my GRE (and subject GRE) scores to the institution when applying the first time, but I did not send them a second time since the GRE requirement was waived due to the pandemic. However, the old scores still appeared in my new application, even though I did not self-report the scores or send in a new score report. I also tried selecting the application option specifying that I had not applied to the program before, but the scores were still present.

I recognize that the department faculty may remember the first application (and scores), but I would like to see if removing the scores from the online application is practically possible.

N.b., this occurred for several PhD programs, so it is not an isolated incident (otherwise I would contact the single department directly to request that the GRE scores be ignored in lieu of the pandemic). This may be related to how most applications seem to use the same/similar website portal and index the applications based on applicant name/birthdate.

Comment: There may not be a general solution.

Comment: At the PhD level the number of applications may not be large. People will remember your recent prior application. And I suppose your GRE scores are still in their system.